# Detect when client connected to wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

From a little bit of reading around, it is my understanding that the only way to detect that a client has connected to my service is through writing my own code. **I am using a Singleton service.** I would like to display a message every time a client connects to my service that client x with ip xxx has connected. There is no built-in event that is generated? Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there's any support in WCF for your requirement.

Not sure what you want to achieve with this, either. Your service class (in your case, just a single instance) really doesn't have any business putting up messages (on screen, I presume) - that really not it's job. The service class is used to handle a request and deliver a response - nothing more.

The `ServiceHost` class might be more of a candidate for this feature - but again, it's job really is to host the service, spin up the WCF runtime etc. - and it's really not a UI component, either.

What you could possibly do is this

- have an Admin UI (a Winforms, console, or WPF app) running on your server alongside your service, providing an admin service to call
- define a fast connection between the two services (using e.g. `netNamedPipe` binding which is perfect for intra-application messaging)
- when your "real" service gets a call, the first thing it does is send out a message to the admin UI which can then pick up that message and handle it

That way, you could cleanly separate your real service and it's job (to provide that service) and the Admin UI stuff you want to do and build a cleanly separated system.

Comment: My Admin UI is running on my server, but not alongside my service, it is responsible for start and stopping my service (Open and Close). 
It also has an instance of my service, which is a question i posted elsewhere. So that's my current setup.

As i expected, and deducted from your answer, if i want to detect clients connecting, keep a list of them, i have to do that on my own, (keep track of things in my own code).

Thanks for your prompt replies.

Comment: A similar question but is there a way for the host program pop up a message box when a client connects to the service?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually implemented my own `connect`, `disconnect` and `ping` service methods which I manually call from my client once the channel has been created.  By using them as a kind of header section in all of my `ServiceContract` interface definitions (and their implementations, of course), they form an makeshift "base service definition" that only requires a bit of cut-n-paste.

The string-based parameters of `connect` and `disconnect` will be used to send client info to the server and return server info and (perhaps a unique connection id) to the client.  In addition a set of timing reference points may make its way in also.

Note how `SessionMode` is required and the individual `OperationContract` properties `IsInitiating` and `IsTerminating` are explicitly specified for each method, the end result being what I would call a "single-session" service in that it defines `connect` and `disconnect` as the sole session bookends.

Note also that the `ping` command will be used as the target of a timer-based "heartbeat" call that tests the service connection state and defeats *ALL* connection timeouts without a single config file :-)

Note also that I haven't determined my fault-handling structure yet which may very well add a method or more and/or require other kinds of changes.

```
   [ServiceContract( SessionMode = SessionMode.Required )]
   public interface IRePropDalSvr {
      [OperationContract( IsInitiating=true, IsTerminating=false )]
      string connect (string pClientInfo);

      [OperationContract( IsInitiating=false, IsTerminating=true, IsOneWay=true )]
      void disconnect (string pClientInfo);

      // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [OperationContract( IsInitiating=false, IsTerminating=false )]
      string ping (string pInp);

      // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // REST OF ServiceContract DEFINITION GOES HERE
```

One caveat:  while I am currently using this code and its implemention in my service classes, I have not verified the code yet.